# QlikView Calculated Dimension

Tags: qlikview

I have the following table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXk1d.jpg)

I need to add a calculated dimension ProductEntryDate based on the following condition:
If the DrugSubstanceFlag = 'Y', then the ProductEntryDate is the Maximum of the 'Patent Expiry Date'.  I will also need to add a calculated dimension 'RestrainingPatent' which is the Patent Number matching the ProductEntryDate. So in this case the ProductEntryDate will be '24/11/2016' and the RestrainingPatent will be '7326708'. How can this be accomplished in QlikView?  Thanking you in advance

Comment: Sorry, the ProductEntryDate will be '24/11/2026'

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: ProductEntryDate: =if(IsNull(GFExclusivityDate and GDrugSubstanceFlag = 'Y'),Aggr(Max({<GDrugSubstanceFlag = {'Y'}>}GFPatentExpiryDate),GTradeName),Aggr(Max(if(GFPatentExpiryDate> GFExclusivityDate and GDrugSubstanceFlag = 'Y', GFPatentExpiryDate,GFExclusivityDate)), GFExclusivityDate))

Comment: RestratingPatent: =if(if(IsNull(ExclusivityDate and DrugSubstanceFlag = 'Y'),Aggr(Max({<DrugSubstanceFlag = {'Y'}>}PatentExpiryDate),TradeName),Aggr(Max(if(PatentExpiryDate> ExclusivityDate and DrugSubstanceFlag = 'Y', PatentExpiryDate,ExclusivityDate)), ExclusivityDate)),if(DrugSubstanceFlag = 'Y', PatentNumber))

Comment: The above is what i have tried so far

Comment: it might be easier trying to do it via the script

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  Do you have any suggestions doing it via the script?